# Animating sprites using single sprite sheet

Tags: animation, libgdx, texturepacker

I was previously animating different states  of a sprite (standing/walking/jumping) by having a separate .png and a textureAtlas file for each of those state. It was working fine. Now I went and combined those seperate sheets into a single png and generated a single `.pack` file.  Now I can access these states by region but they no longer animate? only the first sprite of each state gets drawn, not the entire animation.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas2;
    private Animation animation;
    private Animation animation2;
    private Animation currentAnimation;
    private float elapsedTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("Wolverine.txt"));
        animation = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas.findRegion("Standing"));
        animation2 = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas.findRegion("Walking"));
        currentAnimation = animation;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        textureAtlas.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        //sprite.draw(batch);
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        batch.draw(currentAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT) {
            currentAnimation = animation2;
        }
            return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the data file I'm using with the spritesheet

```
Wolverine.png
size: 256, 256
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
Standing
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
Standing
  rotate: false
  xy: 64, 0
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 2
Standing
  rotate: false
  xy: 128, 0
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 3
Walking
  rotate: false
  xy: 192, 0
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
Walking
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 64
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 2
Walking
  rotate: false
  xy: 64, 64
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 3
Walking
  rotate: false
  xy: 128, 64
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 4
Walking
  rotate: false
  xy: 192, 64
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 5
Walking
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 128
  size: 64, 64
  orig: 64, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 6
```

Comment: please attach your `.pack` file content

Comment: Ok I've appended the data file i'm using for spritesheet in the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are providing to the `Animation` constructor just one animation frame. To be precise you are using this constructor:

```
    public Animation(float frameDuration, TextureRegion... keyFrames)
```

with only one frame. You need to pass to the **Animation** all frames that you want to be inside your animation.

Inside your `textureAtlas` all *Standing* or *Walking* sprites are being name just **Standing** or **Walking** when actually they should be named for example

```
    Standing0
    Standing1
    Standing2
    ...
```

and

```
    Walking0
    Walking1
    Walking2
    Walking3
    ...
```

with order of they are in animation. Rename files of your animation like this before packing them into texture atlas or as a hot-fix you can just rename them inside your `.pack` file.

Then you can use

```
    public Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> findRegions(java.lang.String name)
```

method to get all *Standing/Walking like* frames to pass them to the Animation so:

```
    textureAtlas.findRegions("Standing")
```

Comment: Much Obliged, Although I found that the datasheet works even when the sprites are named as is. What I was doing wrong is I was calling `findRegion()` Instead of `findRegions()`.